# Missing SharePointContext.cs and TokenHelper.cs files in the SharePoint project solution

Tags: nuget-package, sharepoint-online

Missing SharePointContext.cs and TokenHelper.cs files in the SharePoint project solution even after adding the SharePointOnlinePnPCore nuGet package? So how to get those files in the SharePoint solution?

Comment: please provide more information. what is your sharepoint version? what have you tried? and some more info that help others to figure out a solution.

Comment: I am using sharepoint online. I have provided the answer as well which I figured out later. Please check its answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it does happens so try adding another nuGet package in the SharePoint project solution by searching **AppForSharePointWebToolkit** package and install it. This solution worked for me, hope it works for you guys as well!